# Recovering SSD after Ubuntu live USB corrupted partition table?

Tags: disk-utility, partition, unix, apfs

I'm running a mid-2012 MBP with a WD green SSD inside. I needed to install Ubuntu for university so I tried to do so via a live USB. While doing the installation I accidentally clicked on the option to erase my entire drive and install Ubuntu but **I pressed back as soon as I saw the partitioning wizard show up**. So it shouldn't have done anything, right?

I then clicked on the other option which allows you to install on a specific partition, but noticed that I had a bunch of these Linux partitions that I haven't made. After rebooting I found that I can no longer boot to macOS. After some googling I found [someone else with the same problem.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967385/how-do-i-recover-the-apfs-partition-of-a-macbook-using-ubuntu). They claim that the Ubuntu installer:

> overwrote a whopping 2MB of the APFS container without confirmations or warnings

Their solution was to format and reinstall macOS. I unfortunately have some important notes on there that I hadn't backed up, is there any chance that they could be recovered?

I already tried using disk utility in internet recovery, but it just tells me that in order to repair the drive I need to "run disk utility in recovery", which is nonsense as I'm already in recovery. After some more googling I found that using diskutil through command line could work, but after running `diskutil verifyDisk /dev/disk1` and `diskutil verifyDisk /dev/disk1` I get the error message:

> Error: -69767 This disk doesn't contain an EFI system partition; if you want to start up your computer with this disk or include it in a RAID set, back up your data and partition this disk

Which leads me to believe that I need to remake my EFI partition? This is what `diskutil list` shows:

[image: terminal]

It goes all the way up to disk19 with tiny <5mb partitions.